# oh-my-zsh spaceship them error - no such file or directory

Tags: terminal, oh-my-zsh

I have installed `oh-my-zsh` along with spaceship theme in the past but recently I change the username folder in mac users which affected the theme.

When I open `iterm`, the theme is not there and I get this error:

```
/Users/someuser/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:source:118: no such file or directory: /Users/someuser/.oh-my-zsh/themes/spaceship.zsh-theme
```

I went into `.zshrc`, to change the the `export ZSH=..`, but it's still not fixing the problem.

It's complaining it can find the spaceship theme but it looks like theme is in another folder, `/Users/someuser/.oh-my-zsh/custom/theme`.

Not sure, how to let `oh-my-zsh` know to look in the custom folder.  Has anyone encountered this issue? your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 11):

According to the installation guide from spaceship-prompt. Spaceship-prompt is cloned, and symlinked into oh-my-zsh's custom theme folder.

> Clone this repo:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt.git "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship-prompt"
> ```
>
> Symlink spaceship.zsh-theme to your oh-my-zsh custom themes directory:
>
> ```
> ln -s "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship-prompt/spaceship.zsh-theme" "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship.zsh-theme"
> ```
>
> Set `ZSH_THEME="spaceship"` in your `.zshrc`.

The symlink was created with an absolute path. Once your username folder is changed, the **symlink is broken**.

Re-doing the symlink again is enough to fix it.

```sh
ln -sf "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship-prompt/spaceship.zsh-theme" "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship.zsh-theme"
```

Answer (score 1):

So far the only fix to this issue was removing `spaceship-them` from custom folder and reinstalling it again.